# Use environment variable in index.html file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm working on an Angular app where I use an external JavaScript lib:

```
 <-- the end of the body element -->
 <div id="webapps-sidepanel"></div>
 <script src="./assets/js/tecportalapps.js"></script>

 <script>
   $select('#webapps-sidepanel').getWebapps(localStorage.getItem('TMP_username'));
 </script>
</body>
```

Everything works but now the name of the local storage variable name has changed and I need to take the name of environment which is located in the environment.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  *envName*: 'PROD',
};
```

So I need to use something like this:

```
 $select('#webapps-sidepanel').getWebapps(localStorage.getItem('TMP_*envName*'));
```

Is this possible?
Any idea on how I can achieve this is welcome. Maybe I can call the $select from the app.component.ts?

Comment: You mean like `localStorage.getItem('TMP_' + environment.envName)`?

Comment: @Lain, yes but if I want to use it like this I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: environment is not defined

Comment: Well, if you want to use it, you will have to define/include it somewhere/somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the index.html you are out of the context of Angular yet, so you have no chance of reading the value of your environment file.

**Try executing your code in the app.component.ts.**

To be able to do this, you have to make typescript recognize $select as an existing function. There are a couple of ways to do this (read more: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/declaring-global-variables-in-typescript)

Example, `app.component.ts`:

```js
(window as any).$select('#webapps-sidepanel').getWebapps(localStorage.getItem('TMP_' + environment.envName));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add your script from app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScript();
  }

  public loadScript() {
    /* Create your script */
    const body = <HTMLDivElement> document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = './assets/js/tecportalapps.js';

    /* Do your stuff with environement variable or localstorage */
    console.log(environment.envName);
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("envName"));

    /* add your script to DOM */
    body.appendChild(script);
  }

}
```

Comment: It's totally ok to import the script in the index.html as it originally was. The key is to execute the enviroment dependent code in the context of Angular (`app.component.ts`)